# Your application must have a valid targetSdkVersion set

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio-3.0, google-play-console

I bought an app created with Cordova. I create a signed apk in Android Studio but when I try to publish the app in the Play Market I get an error:"Your application must have a valid targetSdkVersion set. To solve this problem, you need to edit your AndroidManifest.xml file and upload again the .apk file."

My config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
```

My Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:targetSdkVersion="29"
        tools:ignore="GradleOverrides" />
```

Answer (score 0):

paste this in your manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="29"/>
```